# JS - Toggle all DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css

My issue involves multiple DIVs that `display:block` or `display:none` each with their own anchor tag. The main problem is that I have recommissioned the JS code that runs this feature without completely understanding it. All I need is a way to toggle all of the DIVs with a single "Show All/Hide All" link. I cannot wrap my head around it.

I have tried absolutely everything that my exceptionally limited grasp will allow - which consists mostly of swinging my arms in the dark and hoping I accidently build a miracle. Since that hasn't worked I am shamefully seeking help.

The only thing that makes this question unique are all the variables with this specific issue -

An (almost) working example can be found at: [www.robertmeans.com/menu.htm](http://www.robertmeans.com/offsite_files/code_help/menu.htm)

The JS code:

```
imageX01='plus';
imageX02='plusEven';

function toggleOdd(ee){
imgX="imagePM"+ee;
divX="div"+ee;
imageX="imageX"+ee;
divLink="divHref"+ee;
imageXval=eval("imageX"+ee);
element = document.getElementById(divX).style;
if (element.display=='none') {element.display='block';}
else {element.display='none';}
if (imageXval=='plus') {document.getElementById(imgX).src='_images/minus.gif';eval("imageX"+ee+"='minus';");document.getElementById(divLink).title='Hide Content';}
else {document.getElementById(imgX).src='_images/plus.gif';eval("imageX"+ee+"='plus';");document.getElementById(divLink).title='Show Content';}
}

function toggleEven(ee){
imgX="imagePM"+ee;
divX="div"+ee;
imageX="imageX"+ee;
divLink="divHref"+ee;
imageXval=eval("imageX"+ee);
element = document.getElementById(divX).style;
if (element.display=='none') {element.display='block';}
else {element.display='none';}
if (imageXval=='plusEven') {document.getElementById(imgX).src='_images/minusEven.gif';eval("imageX"+ee+"='minusEven';");document.getElementById(divLink).title='Hide Content';}
else {document.getElementById(imgX).src='_images/plusEven.gif';eval("imageX"+ee+"='plusEven';");document.getElementById(divLink).title='Show Content';}
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="task_item01">
    <a href="javascript:toggleOdd('01')" id="divHref01"><img src="_images/plus.gif" alt="" name="imagePM01" width="33" height="33" border="0" class="task_itemPlusImage" id="imagePM01" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:toggleOdd('01')">Div #1</a>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" id="div01">
    Content 1
</div>

<!-- ********************************  Item 1 End  **************************** -->
<!-- ********************************  Item 2 Start  ************************** -->

<div id="task_item02">
    <a href="javascript:toggleEven('02')" id="divHref02"><img src="_images/plusEven.gif" alt="" name="imagePM01" width="33" height="33" border="0" class="task_itemPlusImage" id="imagePM02" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:toggleEven('02')">Div #2</a>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" id="div02">
    Content 2
</div>
```

I have spent countless hours trying to work this out on my own. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all, it seems like way too much code to me... you can do this very easily by using jQuery. I have made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nr2f6/4/

Here is some simple html to help you better understand what is being done:

```
<div id="item-1"><span class="plus"></span>Open these items</div>
<div class="contents" data-rel="item-1">
    I have superb items in this div... the world is about to understand just how awesome I am!
</div>

<div id="item-2"><span class="plus"></span>Open these other items</div>
<div class="contents" data-rel="item-2">
    I have amazing contents in this div. I want to show them to the world!
</div>
```

as you can see above, there is no inline css. All the styling (display: none) should be placed separately, to not conflict with what you are trying to do. So simply place it in a separate css file.Then run this code:

```
  $("div[id^=item]").click(function(){
   var reference2open = $(this).attr("id");
   //get the data-rel attribute associated
   $("div[data-rel='"+reference2open+"']").slideToggle();
   $("span",this).toggleClass('minus');
});

$("#all").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('close')){
       $("div[data-rel^=item]").slideUp();
       $("div[id^=item] span").removeClass('minus');
       $("#all").removeClass('close');
        $("#all").html('open them all');
    }else{
    //open and close them all by clicking
    $("div[data-rel^=item]").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':hidden')){
            $(this).slideDown();
            $("div[id^=item] span").addClass('minus');
            $("#all").html('close them all');
        }
    });
    //change the button to close
    $("#all").addClass('close');
    }
    //$("div[id^=item] span").toggleClass('minus');
});
```

****ADDED IN THE TOGGLE PLUS AND MINUS SIGNS USING CSS****

```
.plus{
    background: url(http://www.robertmeans.com/offsite_files/code_help/_images/plus.gif);
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.minus{
    background: url(http://www.robertmeans.com/offsite_files/code_help/_images/minus.gif);
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Do not forget to include your jQuery file! Hope this helps :)

Just wanted to add in some details for better understanding:

**div[id^=item]**: Is saying whenever a div is clicked that has an id that starts with (^=) item, run the code.

**$("div[data-rel='"+reference2open+"']").slideToggle()**: is saying take the id from the div that was clicked and find the content box where with the same name but in the data-rel attribute. The slide it down, if it is already down, slide it back up (toggle). You do not have to use a slide effect, I just thought it was more fun!

Then last but not least, the function you were looking for: How to open them all at once. Again we are using the (^=) to find all of the divs.

**$("div[data-rel^=item").slideToggle();**: So here we are saying to jQuery, hey toggle all the boxes that have a data-rel attribute that starts with (^=) item.

This last part is pretty neat, because you can create many instances of the item-? boxes and this code will work for any number of them. You can also add the same code to a different div, like even and odd, and toggle all the even and all the odd elements accordingly.

Comment: I have changed my response above. I think the easiest and fastest way to achieve this is by using jquery. You can take the code above and place what you currently have in your divs. You can add as many as you want and it will still work. :)

Comment: I see what you mean now by inline css - where I have display:none in the DIV tag. I am trying to hold on to the + and - image feature in my example (see link in OP).

Comment: There you go the edit is above. I hope this helps you! I have been in those dilemmas where you just want to hit your head against a wall. Check out the jsfiddle update to see the function. If this did work for you please add a checkmark by the question! This helps others know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Are you a wizard? That's great and I like the slideToggle() effect. One final detail - if I have one open and one closed and click, "Open them all" it just reverses whatever state they are in instead of forcing them all opened or all closed. - THANK YOU!

Comment: Perfect.. I edited the code above:
 $("div[data-rel^=item").hide();
Just need to add this to make sure it hides all divs before toggling all. Hope this does it for you ;)

Comment: I see you're banging your head now. :)

Comment: hahaha yeah but I bang till it bleeds! Edited above :).. this should be the final edit (hopefully). Hope it helps! See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nr2f6/4/

Comment: YEEHAW! You Rock! This is one brilliant piece of code for the world that you have created. Awe-frekin'-some! Thank you! This site rocks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49359/discussion-between-lylecrumbstorm-and-liveandream)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a specific `class` to all the things you want to toggle, then loop through all of them with a toggle function.